# ListView OnItemLongClick ActionMode Error

Tags: android, listview, onitemlongclicklistener, actionmode

I have a programm with a simple `ListView` and set an `OnItemLongClickListener` on it. All fine, Android Studio doesn't show any mistake. But when I `longclick` in the app, the app stopped and Android Studio showed a Runtime Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'boolean android.view.ActionMode$Callback.onCreateActionMode
>   (anddroid.view.ActionMode, android.view.Menu)' on a null object
>   reference

What does `ListView` and `OnItemLongClickListener` have to do with ActionMode?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Reaz Murshed No thats not really the same